# GPS fix Is not happening for the first time. No status in notification bar

Tags: android, gps, android-maps

Created a Location alarm based app. Everything is working fine on emulator. But the following error occurs in real device.

Scenario:

Turned on GPS.
Opened my app in phone. 
No GPS symbol in status bar.
App getting force closed.

To fix this scenario, I am doing the following thing

Open any application like Maps, GPS Essentials.
My GPS values is getting fixed.
Opening my application after that.
App working fine.

Providing the necessary codes below:

in my Oncreate method

```
fixlocation = orgManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    orgManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1000, this);
    orgManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 1000, this);
    mo.enableCompass();
    mo.enableMyLocation();
}

/** Stop the updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    orgManager.removeUpdates(this);
    mo.disableCompass();
    mo.disableMyLocation();
}



@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //orgManager.removeUpdates(this);

        if (location != null) {
            currLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            currLongtitude = location.getLongitude();
}}
```

What do I need to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

currLat = location.getLatitude();
currentLang = location.getLongitude();
```

Try this to get current location.

onLocationChanged will call only when location of your device changes but

first time when your application starts you can use this code.

Comment: Instead of the location u have specified, i have used fixlocation which is also a location object.